# How to find which line crashed Android Application using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I am new to Android Application Development.I want to know the procedure how do i know which line crashed my application to crash.

I have following code in main.java

```
 package com.example.app_list_view_1;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; 
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
 import android.text.AndroidCharacter;
 import android.util.Log; 
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
 import android.view.Menu; 
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup; 
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.os.Build;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Log.d("DEEPAK","HELLO WORLD");

         String[] cityNames =  new String[]{
                                    "A",
                                    "M",
                                    "R",
                                    "H",
         };

         Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
 cityNames);

         ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_1);

         lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);


     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most folks are moving over to Android Studio now a days. Eclipse has a way to view Logcat in one of the tabs. Open that and you will see the line number and stack trace.

From the command-line regardless of IDE you can run:

> $ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools/adb logcat -v threadtime

When the application crashes you will get a stack trace that tells you the stack at the time of the crash.

Another good option is Crashlyitc because that will give you vision into failures in the field.

If you need an advanced log tool check out http://lograbbit.com

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend switching to `Android Studio`, and use the `logcat` output.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html